# My ubuntu 20.04 laptop can't connect to the internet

Tags: internet, dns

I have tried wifi, mobile hotspot and ethernet but none worked. Chrome says it's some kind of dns error. That's about all I know about this problem.
Edit: I downloaded ubuntu, internet was working fine. Then it got an update and the internet stopped working after that, if this information helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a problem with wifi card may it's driver needs an update.Is there wifi icon on notification panel.Does it show that you have wifi on settings